# Require.js file is not supporting

Tags: requirejs, chargify

I found the following issue while running my program. Here I send you the firebug console errors and the files which I included in my html page header part.If any one come to know what the issue is kindly tell me the solution.

### **Firebug console**

> Error: Module name "request" has not been loaded yet for context: _.
>   Use require([]) http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
>   ...c=c[b]});return c}function
>   C(b,c,d,e){c=Error(c+"\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/err...

### **my code**

```
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"

src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.18/minified/require.js"

src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/natevw/node-chargify/ad91cdec92f41d4045bb6e2189e5a04571576bcc/chargify.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

you're not loading requirejs in the proper way. Should be like this :

```
<script data-main="js/your_main_file.js" src="js/require.js"></script>
```

Have a look at [official doc](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html) for more info.